# Creating route got error of Router.use() requires middleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app.js I do

```
app.use('/', require('./routes')); //old routes
app.use('/api', require('./api'));
```

and I have an api folder that have index.js. In my index.js here is how it looks like

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
console.log('fire')
module.exports = router;
```

Strange I did the same thing for my first route, it worked but I got an error of `TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object` in creating this api route. Any idea?

Comment: What does `the first route work` mean?

Comment: Where did you define `router` methods like `get`, `post`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one case used in my project

```
//app.js
var router = express.Router();
app.use('/api/', require('./routes/home')(router));

//./routers/home.js
module.exports = function(router) {
  router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // ...
  });

  return router;
}
```